# Get name of property implicit method was called on

Tags: scala, reflection

Using Scala, I want to achieve the following:

```
// SETUP:

implicit class ExampleOps(s: String) {
  def name: String = ???
}

case class Example(prop1: String, prop2: String)
val e = Example("a", "b")

// BEHAVIOR I WANT:

e.prop1.name // should return "prop1"
```

In this case `def name` somehow knows what it's being called on.  How is this accomplished?

Comment: You could achieve that for some specific cases by using macros. That can get quite involved. A simpler solution is to use a custom wrapper type instead of `String`, like `case class Property(name: String, value: String)`

Comment: The wrapper type was my first idea however the amount of times something needs to be used as it's value vs. knowing it's name is literally like 250:1 so it seemed overkill to go that route unless it was the only option.

Comment: The problem is with `e.prop1.name` you _know_ (and the macro will know) that the name is `prop1`. But if you write `val x = e.prop1; x.name`, you are already lost even with a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the comment, macros could be used to a certain extent. However, they can not magically restore some information that is lost. For example if you store the property value in an arbitrary variable, there is no way to figure out from which property it was read:

```
val x: String = e.prop1
x.name  // no way to know if came from calling e.prop1
```

So I think the only solution is to use a custom type. You could allow them to be unrolled as strings implicitly:

```
object Property {
  implicit def value[A](prop: Property[A]): A = prop.value
}
case class Property[+A](name: String, value: A)

case class Example(value1: String, value2: String) {
  def prop1 = Property("prop1", value1)
  def prop2 = Property("prop2", value2)
}

val e = Example("a", "b")
e.prop1.toUpperCase
e.prop1.name
```